# pip installation error command 'python setup.py egg_info' failed with error code 1

Tags: pip, failed-installation

I am trying to install monkeytype on Ubuntu terminal using the command:

```
pip install monkeytype
```

but I'm getting an error saying:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

Here is the full log:

```
bash-4.3$ pip install monkeytype
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting monkeytype
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/59/43bc6e44d69bd268e545fdfacdd6866362aca57ac894bbc3177b5455c06a/MonkeyType-18.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting retype (from monkeytype)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/da/ca9f5560f051d2ed79a52de1170903e3ff8ad011cff56c65abfcff38d372/retype-17.12.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-mCIobj/retype/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6, 0), "retype requires Python 3.6+"
    AssertionError: retype requires Python 3.6+
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mCIobj/retype/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `pip install`, the real error is always hidden a little further up the log because pip runs the install routine of your packages.

In your case check for `ERROR: Traceback`, which says 'retype requires Python 3.6+'.

So, the installed package requires Python 3.6 but from an earlier error message we can deduce your pip runs python 2.7 (look for `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7` )

So, fix the error by running the command with `pip3` or `python3 pip`.

To verify which version of python is used, call `pip -V`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

copy it and paste it in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error list searching a line like 'WARNING: The wheel package is not available.' or something similar.
Installing separately each missing package resolve the problems.